# Ruby o Rails Rspec - How to validate arguments when creating custom matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to create a validation like the matcher have_http_status to the content_type.

I created the following matcher:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_content_type do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.content_type == expected
  end

  description do
    "respond with content_type #{expected}"
  end
end
```

However, I would like to check if the actual value is a response object. If not, I would like to give a message like the have_http_status, which would be:

```
 Failure/Error: it { expect(legal_person).to have_http_status(200) }
       expected a response object, but an instance of LegalPerson was received
     # ./spec/controllers/legal_people_controller_spec.rb:105:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So when I pass an object different from a request-response object, I would expect an error saying that a response object was expected.

It works without it but would be better if it shows an informative message saying what went wrong exactly.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to have 2 matchers under 1 name. I believe this is a bad practice, and there should be two matchers - one for content type, another one - for checking request/response type. So your tests should look like:

```
expect(response).to be_a(ActionDispatch::Response)
expect(response).to have_content_type('application/json')
```

Also, I don't see any problem of having just content type check. If the object passed does not have `.content_type` method, the matcher will throw corresponding error: `Undefined method 'content_type'` and you should be fine figuring out that you've passed wrong object.

But, if you are still sure you need to check two things in one matcher, check this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_content_type do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    request_or_response?(actual) && actual.content_type.to_s == expected
  end

  description do |actual|
    if request_or_response?(actual)
      "respond with content_type #{expected}"
    else
      "a response object, but an instance of #{actual.class} was received"
    end
  end

  private

  def request_or_response?(actual)
    [Rack::Request, ActionDispatch::Response].any? do |klass|
      actual.is_a?(klass)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In this case,  I am not trying to do is not to have to matchers in one place, but rather just check if the expected the value is a response as it is done with have_http_status RSpec matcher.

Is have_http_status considered as two matcher in one?